# How to configure SoapUI load test?

Tags: soapui, load-testing

I'm setting up some load tests in SoapUI and I'm a bit confused on what exactly is happening.

I'm using the simple strategy.

Does the number of "Threads" equal the number of concurrent requests? So 10 threads means that there will be 10 requests for every run?

My goal is to see how my server will handle ~10 requests/second which I assume means that I need TPS > 10?

Is there any other way to ensure that 10 requests/second are being executed?

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the documentation? http://www.soapui.org/load-testing/getting-started.html Note the additional links along the left side on that page.

Comment: I've looked here briefly, but it doesn't seem like there's a definitive answer to "how do I execute 10 requests per second". I'll keep reading through those in case I missed something!

Comment: Maybe this isn't even a very good test scenario? Maybe the better scenario is number of concurrent users (i.e. threads). Then TPS would give a good idea of how many requests/second the server handled.

Answer (score 0):

After re-reading some of the documentation and hunting around some more it appears that the standard version of SoapUI cannot be used to execute x requests/second. LoadUI has this functionality built in though.

A good fallback plan is to up the number of threads and look at the TPS to make sure that you're achieving your desired requests/second.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, By using simple Strategy you can check if your server can handle 10 threads/ sec.

[image]
TO answer your questions

> Does the number of "Threads" equal the number of concurrent requests?
>   So 10 threads means that there will be 10 requests for every run?

I will explain Meaning of terms:-

1. Threads:-  This is the number of threads i.e. virtual user which are
   going to concurrently call your test step. e.g. 20 virtual users
2. Test Delay and Random:-  this two are used together to provide breathing time(in millisecond) for the server.  After every call of
   by 20 users, it will wait for 1000 millisecond i.e. 1 second.
3. Limit:-  How long time / How many threads it will execute. In the above pic, I have given 60 second time. So, for 1 minute this test
   will run, and after every second 20 threads will be getting called.
4. tps :- thred per second
5. cnt:- how many request has been executed during test.

> My goal is to see how my server will handle ~10 requests/second which
>   I assume means that I need TPS > 10?

Yes, at the end of the test run you able to see tps thread per second which is your server capacity.

If you increase concurrent threads, and if your server can handle / capacity that much stress then tps also increase and cnt (count). But if you give more stress than it can handle tps start decreasing.